# xamarin.forms Access name or ID of checkbox in event handler

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have multiple checkboxes in my view and they are all bound to the same eventhandler.
Now I need to know which checkbox was checked or unchecked inside this eventhandler.

So i tried accessing the name, and funny enough, this is what this looks like:

[image]

As you can see under ID it states the name of checkbox.

When when I try accessing that ID

```
var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
```

[image]

checkbox.Id now has changed to a guid, and is no longer the name of the checkbox (which is something I dont understand either)

How can I pass a param or name to my checkbox to retrieve that in the event handler?

EDIT:

This is NOT workign code (as I canoot access checkbox.Id like this, as it is a guid object not just a string)

```
<CheckBox Color="White"
                                          CheckedChanged="chk_monthly_CheckedChanged"
                                          x:Name="check_daily"                                      
                                          HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                          VerticalOptions="Start"/>

async void chk_monthly_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

            check_daily.CheckedChanged -= chk_monthly_CheckedChanged;
            chk_monthly.CheckedChanged -= chk_monthly_CheckedChanged;
            chk_weekly.CheckedChanged -= chk_monthly_CheckedChanged;

            await Task.Delay(50);

            check_daily.IsChecked = false;
            chk_monthly.IsChecked = false;
            chk_weekly.IsChecked = false;

            checkbox.IsChecked = true;

// not working
            if(checkbox.Id == "check_daily")
            {

            }

            check_daily.CheckedChanged += chk_monthly_CheckedChanged;
            chk_monthly.CheckedChanged += chk_monthly_CheckedChanged;
            chk_wee
```

kly.CheckedChanged += chk_monthly_CheckedChanged;
}

Comment: can you include some code. i guess you can access the checkbox text

Comment: @AmjadS. i just did

Comment: try giving it a type then check its type in the even func

Comment: "type" doesnt exist in the xaml properties for checkbox...

Comment: why you r unsubscribing from the event in your function. i didnt understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION 1

First name the checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbx_laser">
```

Then in the Event Handler Check if the sender is the checkbox

```
if(sender.Equals(cbx_laser)){
    // Do Stuff
    string cbx_name = cbx_laser.Name; // Heres how to get the name
}
```

OPTION 2

Use the sender param and typecast.

```
string cbx_name = ((Checkbox)sender).Name;
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy: just give it a name and then go : if(checkbox.equals (my checkbox) thanks!

Comment: Yeah np. Although It's up to you as the programmer, linking  a bunch of events to a single event handler and checking who the sender is probably considered bad practice. This is because there is extra code being executed when checking who the sender is. If it matters who the sender is it is better to create a separate handler and make use of the xaml binding.